# PHP and MSSQL Connections

Tags: php, sql-server

During the process of linking PHP to MSSQL interlocks, we tried to refer to the answers from other stack over flow for errors.
But the results were largely divided into two.

The difference between the two codes is different in the "$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db) or die("Couldnt connect to server");" section.
In Plan A, we did Username and in Plan B we did UID.
The two errors are also different.
I saw the answers in the "stack over flow" but they are not resolved.
Also, why these errors appear is not solved.
I really need help.

There are many similar questions, and I feel really sorry for asking the same question.
However, I have searched many times. But it doesn't work.

Try A plan

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbusername = "test";
    $dbpassword = "test12";
    $db = "Test_DB";

    $connectionInfo = array("Username" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db) or die("Couldnt connect to server");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);

    if($conn){
      echo "Sucsess";
    }
    else{
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Try B plan

```
<?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbusername = "test";
    $dbpassword = "test12";
    $db = "Test_DB";

    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db) or die("Couldnt connect to server");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);

    if($conn){
      echo "Sucsess";
    }
    else{
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

plan A error result is 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -1 [code] => -1 [2] => Invalid option Username was passed to sqlsrv_connect. [message] => Invalid option Username was passed to sqlsrv_connect. ) )

plan B error result is -
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]������ ������ ������: SQL Server�� ���� ������ �� �� �����ϴ�. [2]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]������ ������ ������: SQL Server�� ���� ������ �� �� �����ϴ�. [2]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]�α��� ���� �ð��� ����Ǿ����ϴ�. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]�α��� ���� �ð��� ����Ǿ����ϴ�. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server�� ������ �����ϴ� �߿� ��Ʈ��ũ ���� �Ǵ� �ν��Ͻ� ���� ������ �߻��߽��ϴ�. ������ ã�� �� ���ų� �׼����� �� �����ϴ�. �ν��Ͻ� �̸��� �ùٸ��� SQL Server�� ���� ������ ����ϵ��� �����Ǿ� �ִ��� Ȯ���Ͻʽÿ�. �ڼ��� ������ SQL Server �¶��� �������� �����Ͻʽÿ�. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server�� ������ �����ϴ� �߿� ��Ʈ��ũ ���� �Ǵ� �ν��Ͻ� ���� ������ �߻��߽��ϴ�. ������ ã�� �� ���ų� �׼����� �� �����ϴ�. �ν��Ͻ� �̸��� �ùٸ��� SQL Server�� ���� ������ ����ϵ��� �����Ǿ� �ִ��� Ȯ���Ͻʽÿ�. �ڼ��� ������ SQL Server �¶��� �������� �����Ͻʽÿ�. ) )

Comment: You know that `or die("Couldnt connect to server")` should go after `sqlsrv_connect()`, not after you populate an array?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Actually this `die` is completely superfluous here.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Yeah but That is not solution..

Comment: `$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db); $conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo)` will work if your SQL Server allows SQL authentication and the credentials are correct.